# How to force -drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates: to take snapshots at @2x resolution?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7, core-graphics

`-drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` is a [fast way](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawViewHierarchyInRect%3aafterScreenUpdates%3a) in iOS 7 to take a snapshot of a view hierarchy.

It takes snapshots but with @1x resolution. The snapshots look pixellated and blurry on an iPhone 5S. The view from which I create a snapshot is not transformed.

I don't want to blur it and want good quality as seen on screen.
Here is how I capture it:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
[self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I also tried:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, self.contentScaleFactor);
```

which still renders with low @1x quality.

Is there another way to configure the image context so it's @2x resolution?

Answer (score 14):

The correct one would be:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0f);
```

Comment: Why 0 for scale factor?

Comment: See [documentation of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions `](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions): "The scale factor to apply to the bitmap. If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen."

Comment: Yes, the documentation states it clearly. Unless you need a specific scale factor, always use 0.0.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the problem was that self.contentScaleFactor returns a wrong value on a retina display device. It is 1 where it should be 2.

This works, but of course it's less than ideal because it has no fallback for non-retina devices.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 2);
```

Comment: I would take a look at @graver's answer... using 0.0 for the scale factor should suit your needs.

Comment: Yes, @graver's answer is correct if you're looking for device resolution.